# SS & Transparency blue tint fix (eevee)

Tags: transparency, eevee-render-engine

When a transparent material hits a surface with ss enabled, the edges appear blueish. The only way I could fix it is by enabling Screen Space Refractions on the hair, but that disables all the shadows it casts on the skin. Any known fix?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Eevee treats transparent objects differently than Cycles. They are sorted from front-to-back per object and do not receive any screen space effects.

This is fast and works fine for many cases, but it is only approximate and gives incorrect results for some object shapes. For more accurate results, enable Alpha Hashed transparency in the material. With a sufficient number of samples to resolve the noise, this gives accurate transparency.